# How to make Flask log to stdout instead of stderr?

Tags: python, flask, logging

Flask does all kinds of logging automatically, for example when receiving a POST request Flask will automatically log it:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2019 18:18:16] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> ```

The problem is that this logging is done to `stderr`, I would like it to instead do all the same logging, with the default formatting, but log to `sys.stdout` instead.

I've tried something like this:

```
import logging
import sys

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

And based on [Flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/logging) I tried:

```
import sys
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'sys.stdout',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

But the first one doesn't have the desired effect and the second one just crashes.

Comment: `'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you, that worked perfectly! Feel free to post that as an actual answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [@RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest)'s comment, this did the job:

```
import sys
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # <-- Solution
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```